# How to use CriteriaQuery to query collection that gets persisted as a string using @Convert annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

In a SpringBoot app using Hibernate, I have an entity similar to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Convert(converter = IntegerListConverter.class) //this maps a set of integers to a string, and vice versa when writing to the DB
    @Column(name = "types", nullable = false)
    private Set<Integer> types;

    //other members, getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

I'm doing a search based on several parameters and therefore the query has to be built programmatically to filter based on the variable input. I want to write a query equivalent to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_entity
WHERE id IN (:ids)
  AND types LIKE '%:type%';
```

or equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM my_entity
WHERE id IN (:ids)
  AND CONCAT(',', types) LIKE '%,:type%';
```

When using the first approach the persistence layer complains about *types* not being a Set.
The second approach works if I write it using a `@Query` annotation but I can't really use that since, like I mentioned before, the query is built conditionally depending on the user filter.
One additional note, I'm performing the query on a large dataset (i.e. ~100K matching entries) on MySQL, and running separate queries will involve transferring a lot of data which makes it slow (i.e. ~20 seconds).

*Note: Please don't ramble about how bad it is to store one-to-many relationships on the same table. There are trade-offs that were considered and the system is designed like that for a reason.*

Help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to store `types` as a String with the original serialised value (i.e. without `@Convert`), then possibly add a "fake getter" that parses it and returns a `Set<Integer>`. This will allow you building the SQL query the way you need. There might be other options I'm not aware of though.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate it with @Basic then this should work. IMO you should consider using the JSON type in MySQL instead to avoid the custom "parsing" that you have to do to be able to find individual values. I think you can even index this properly when you switch to JSON.